# How to access dynamic segment in a controller in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I have an example route:

```
this.route('client', {path: ':id'});
```

I can access this in my route like this:

```
model: function(params) {
    console.log(params.id);
}
```

How do I access the `:id` in my controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I do it in my application. Not sure if this is the best approach.

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    this.set('params', params);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('params', this.get('params'));
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
});
```

Alternatively you can also do a lookup on the container inside your controller. But I dont really think this is a good approach. Here is an example.

```
this.get('container').lookup('router:main').router.currentHandlerInfos
        .findBy('name','index').params
```

Comment: I would also suggest skipping setupController part and just return Hash from model() hook.

Comment: @XLII In my use case I also needed to return an actual model. So I used the setupController method for params.

Comment: YMMV, but if that's the sole setupController role you could do something along the lines `function(c,p) { return {obj: ..., params: p}; }`, but it's rather matter of requirements and personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

There's a serialize function within the Route that you can take advantage of. Here's the [API Documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize) for it. However, in your context, you can just do this:

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    console.log(params.client_id);
  },
  serialize: function(model){
    return { client_id : model.id };
  }
});
```

Let me know if this works!

I also noticed an error in your route definition. It should presumably be

```
this.route('client', {path: '/:client_id'});
```

or

```
this.route('client', {path: '/client/:client_id'});
```

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

If your id happens to be part of your model you can retrieve from the model itself.
For example, if you have a route with an object Bill as a model, and the path bills/:billId, on your controller you can retrieve it this way:

this.get('model').id

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question since I too was wondering what was the best way to do this. I chose to go via the route of returning a hash from the model rather than setting parameters in the route.

So in your case I would do the following:

```
model() {
  Ember.RSVP.hash({client: <get client>, id: id});
}
```

And then in the controller or template I can access the client by calling

```
model.client
```

and get the id by calling

```
model.id
```

I personally feel this is a cleaner way of accessing the id as compared to setting a param on the route. Of course I am assuming that the id is not already set on the model. Otherwise this entire exercise is pointless.